# Power Bi how to calculate Net Present Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

i hope someone can help me.

I have several files (10 at least) connected by YEAR (just as number, not date) and CASE, and for each file I have a cash flow (i upload pbix sample file with 3 files only to simplify things)

So i Have Flow A, Flow B, Flow C, by year (not as date type) and not always Flow A has a value in a year corresponding for Flow B or C as can be seen on visuals

I created a measure for Total Flow and that works perfect.

But now, i need to calculate net present value for TOTAL FLOW and i was thinking in creating a Calculated Column with sum of Flow A, B and C, and then use XNPV...... but i get a total result for all rows in my column, I have my tables with relation to table with year and case, so i don't understand why can i just sum up 3 columns, by rows. It looks simple on excel,  but not efficient if i chose that way

Creating a measure for XNPV it's not working, i get constan error (4 arguments)

I don't want to create a new excel file for getting NPV because it's to slow and i already did it and my dataset it's constantly changing (adding more CASES)

Any orientation ? How can i get in Power Bi, Net present value for Total FLow?

Thank you in advance

[PBIX Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YJpRFeJumWtHDlhYVjpeq1rMklnszZd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: NPV is dependent on the order of input values. How is this order to be determined in your case across after combining the different flows?

Comment: Also, you've tagged DAX so I presume for some reason you don't want to first combine your separate tables into a further table via Power Query? This would be the logical first step, though it can also be achieved via combining the tables using DAX alone.